# How to use MapView in google map V2 android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use onTouch events (to handle the rotation gesture of an object on map). I cannot do it with extending the Activity in mainActivity and using fragments. So I guess I should use MapView class. How can I do this in new version of google maps android (V2)?
This will show nothing. a blank white screen on phone only.

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 // MapView mapV;
 // GoogleMap map;



 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapV = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.map));
    map = mapV.getMap();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use MapFragment? What's your issue on using MapFragment?

Comment: The thing I want to do is being able to rotate an object (a marker) on map. I was thinking maybe by using mapview I can access to ontouch events which are for view class.. dont know maight be i am wrong. but I dont know how to solve this

Comment: What do you mean by rotate? there are also on tap/touch listeners for MapFragment.

Comment: There is a marker I will put on map now I want to be able to rotate it (by 2 fingers) and save the angle

Comment: I think you can do that in MapFragment.

Comment: First you have to have working map.

Comment: yes i have it with fragment in xml file as Google developers site described. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you have to implement all the life cycle methods (onPause, etc) and in there forward it on to your map, e.g.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    map.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```